Spring Boot JPA update using composite primary keys
I have events table with composite key on id, created_at.
My SQL query is as below:
update events set status = true where (id, created_at) in ((1, '2024-06-17 12:00:44.674394+01'), (id2, time2), (id3, time3)...)

How to achieve this in Spring boot JPA? I tried below code:
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query(
      value = """
          UPDATE events
          SET status = true 
          WHERE (id, created_at) IN (:pkValues)
          """,
      nativeQuery = true
  )
  int updateStatus(List<Object[]> pkValues);

But I got error:

[ERROR: operator does not exist: record = bytea   Hint: No operator
matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add
explicit type casts.   Position: 87] [n/a].

Any help is highly appreciated.

It would be nice if you could privide the generated SQL from the output log. Or is that exactly the SQL that you mentioned first?

Generated sql: [UPDATE events  SET status = true
WHERE (id, created_at) IN (?,?)
]

The problem is in :pkValues, you supply something that not expected. Why in generated sql there are only two question marks  IN(?,?) when we supply a list?


Create your Id as @Embeddable e.g. MyPkEmebddable
Make use of your Id Type in your class using @EmbeddedId e.g.
@EmbeddedId MyPkEmbeddable yourIdField;
Make your JPQL Statement using the type

@Query(value = "UPDATE events SET status = true WHERE yourIdField IN (:pkValues)...  )
int updateStatus(List<MyPkEmbeddable> pkValues)
JPA layers Objects around the tables, so a composite primary key is set up as an @EmbeddableId
see https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jpa-embedded-method-parameters
This should do the trick :-)

Wow, Easier than expected. Thankyou @gorefest.
